# htaccess rule not working perfectly

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my htaccess rules not working
i dont want to display php extension
my rule

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^WHMCS/?$ 404.php [L]  
RewriteRule .*\.php$ 404.php [L]       
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php  [L]
RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ ./page.php?page=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^comments$ ./comments.php [L]
```

but when i open url without any extention then also it is showing me 404 error
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out this rule: `RewriteRule .*\.php$ 404.php [L]` and use this rule at the **end of your rules**:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: but if some one use .php extension then it should show 404 error

Comment: If someone uses `.php` extension then it should redirect with 301 to non-php one. Let me know if you need it.